# PS2 barcode scanner doesn't work

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I have problem with Zebex Z-3000 barcode scanner. It is connected to my PC via PS2 port. Does anybody knows about PS2 scanners. I had no problem with USB scanners but I ca't get PS2 scanners work. Do I have to listen PS2 port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, usually PS/2 scanners will simulate keypresses as if the barcode's value had been typed on the keyboard.

Is it recognising the barcode but not sending data, or not even beeping?

Scanners generally come with (or you can obtain) a set of configuration barcodes to control the types of codes it recognises and how the values are formatted (whether it appends a carriage-return, for example). You could try contacting the manufacturer or scour [their website](http://www.zebex.com/supports_services/documentation.sbu.htm) (now that it's working again) to find these.

Comment: Barcode scanner works with one of installed programs but does not print data on any other place, like notepad or where the pointer is.

Comment: Does it just happen on that PC? Is there a keyboard attached? Some kind of weird interaction with NumLock perhaps?

Comment: No just mouse attached. I cannot perform a test on another PC.

Answer (score 2):

PS/2 barcode scanners are "keyboard wedge" scanners that plug in between a PS/2 keyboard and a computer's [PS/2 port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector). When a barcode is scanned, they send the data to the computer as if it were keyboard input.

The ZEBEX Z-3000 barcode scanner has [a set of configuration barcodes](http://www.zebex.com/Product/documents/Z-3000/Z-3000_ProgrammingGuide_100730.pdf). Try to use those to get the scanner working if when you try scanning into Notepad, the scanner does not send any data. The scanner might be incorrectly set to RS-232C or USB mode (instead of PC/AT mode), or the barcode symbology you are trying to scan might not be enabled.

(Users of other models of barcode scanners should consult their respective manufacturers' programming guides instead.)

Comment: So it's exactly like USB type scanner? But why I can't read any data from it?

Comment: The link appears to have gone dead.

Comment: @XTL: The manufacturer seems to have reorganized their website. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a barcode scanner with PS/2 connector. A "keyboard wedge" y connector to be precise. When I plug only the scanner to the PC and perform scanning, I only head a beep sound without any text written in text editor, which I use to test it.
Now, when I plug a PS/2 keyboard into the Y connector, so it's keyboard+scanner connected to the PS/2 port, I could see some text written in the text editor when performing test.

So, the key point is that you need to have the keyboard attached to the Y connector.